# How can add step to step keys and vlaue to three different select option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, html-select

I have three select box for state, city, and district I want join data with array in array and send this to jQuery then add all keys to State select box options value then every state option selected add keys of this array to city select box options value and every option of city selected add value of this key to district select box option value,
if you want asking if all of them added to value of options so what happen for name of options I should tell you I want add name from other array

**HTML:**

```
<select class="State"></select>
<select class="City"></select>
<select class="district"></select>
```

**Simple Array:**

```
array ( 
    "nevada" => array (
        "carson-city" =>  ( district-1, district-2, district-3),
        "las-vegas" =>  ( district-1, district-2, district-3) 
    )

    "new-york" => array (
        "albany" =>  ( district-1, district-2, district-3),
        "new-york" =>  ( district-1, district-2, district-3) 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your array in JSON format:

```
var LocationsArray = '[
    {
      "state": "nevada",
      "cities": {
           "carson-city": { "districts":"district-1,district-2,district-32"  },
           "las-vegas": { "districts":"district-1,district-2,district-32"  }
        }
    },
    {
      "state": "new-york",
      "cities": {
           "albany": { "districts":"district-1,district-2,district-32"  },
           "new-york": { "districts":"district-1,district-2,district-32"  }
        }
    }
]';
```

Then you react to the Change event of the ComboList:

```
$('#State').on('change', function() {
    var mSelectedValue = $(this).val();
    var mCityCombo = $("#City");
    mCityCombo.empty();
    mCityCombo.append('<option></option>');


        var json = JSON.parse(LocationsArray);
        $.each(JSON.parse(json), function (idx, obj) {
            if (obj.state == 'arizona') {
                // here you add the Cities:
               obj.cities.forEach(function (_city) { 
                var opt = $("<option>" + _city + "</option>").attr("value", recorrido);
                mCityCombo.append(opt);
            }
        });

    mCityCombo.selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Something like that, i really didnt test this code.
Good luck.